# AWS CDK. How to pass `id` of first stack to second stack

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've a project with multiple stacks, but with common `stacks.ts` file.

- My 1 stack creates a VPC
- My 2 stack creates a ECS

---

Stack `vpc.tf`

```
export class stack-vpc extends Stack {
   constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: props) {
       super(scope, id, props);
       new ec2.Vpc(this, 'dev-vpc', {
           cidr: "10.0.0.0/16",
           vpcName: "dev-vpc"
       })
   }
}
```

Stack `ecs.tf`

```
export interface Istack-ecs extends StackProps {
   vpc: ec2.Vpc;
}


export class stack-ecs extends Construct {
   constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: Istack-ecs) {
       super(scope, id);
       new ecs.Cluster(this, "fargate", {
           vpc: props.vpc,
           clusterName: "test",
           enableFargateCapacityProviders: true
       });
   }
}
```

---

Here is the `stacks.ts` file

```
const app = new cdk.App();
const vpc = new stack-vpc(app, "Dev_VPC_CF", props);
const ecs = new stack-ecs(app, "Dev_ECS_CF", props);
```

The `vpc` is creating without any problem, however once I'm putting an ecs to my stack the cdk gives me the error:

```
[Error at /stack-ecs] Could not find any VPCs matching {"account":"__--__","region":"eu-central-1",
"filter":{"tag:Name":"stack-vpc","isDefault":"false"},
"returnAsymmetricSubnets":true,
"lookupRoleArn":"arn:aws:iam::__--__:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-__--__-eu-central-1"}
```

`cdk.context.json` is retrieving correct values from my aws credentials, so I can't blame the authentification, so my problem I need to somehow wait until one stack will give me an output so I can use it in my other stacks

Comment: Can you @gshpychka provide an examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fedonev said

> The fromLookup methods are for referencing existing deployed resources.

So instead you can do something like this:

1. Your `vpc` should export `ec2.Vpc`
2. `Construct` won't work in your case, you need to extend from `cdk.Stack`
3. Since your `ecs` interface `Istack-ecs` already expecting a `vpc`

```
const app = new cdk.App();
const your_vpc = new stack-vpc(app, "Dev_VPC_CF", props);
const your_ecs = new stack-ecs(app, "Dev_ECS_CF", {
    vpc: your_vpc.vpc // As your props expects one single value
});
your_ecs.addDependency(your_vpc); // Guarantees That your `vpc` will be created firstly
app.synth();
```

Comment: Thank you again @Bow Bow! Yes your solution worked for me. As well the `Dependency` methods looks really good

Answer (score 1):

The `fromLookup` methods are for referencing existing deployed resources.  This is not what you want.  Instead, use Typescript language features to pass constructs within and between stacks.  As @gshpychka explains in the comments, there are several CDK patterns:

For a simple app, a single stack with a Vpc and Ecs resources is a [good approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-separate).  The `cdk-examples` repo has several such [ECS examples with a Vpc](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/ecs):

```js
export class MySingleStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: props) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'dev-vpc', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      vpcName: 'dev-vpc',
    });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'Ec2Cluster', { vpc });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, pass a Vpc reference between stacks in the same app.  VpcStack exports a Vpc.  EcsStack's props should extend `cdk.StackProps`, adding a `vpc: ec2.Vpc` attribute. The vpc is exported from VpcStack and passed to EcsStack as a prop:

```js
// vpc.ts
export class VpcStack extends Stack {
  readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: props) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'dev-vpc', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      vpcName: 'dev-vpc',
    });
  }
}


// stacks.ts
const app = new cdk.App();
const { vpc } = new VpcStack(app, 'Dev_VPC_CF', props);
new EcsStack(app, 'Dev_ECS_CF', { ...props, vpc });
```

Comment: Thank you @fedonev, I've used your suggestion and extended `StackProps` however now it is creating a separate `vpc` for `ecs` cluster, and after it creates vpc of mine

Comment: @Neon - I can't see your updated code, so it's difficult to say what your mistake is.

Comment: the `ecs.ts` updated